# react native : What is the way to mark the checkbox when clicking on the BOB text?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, redux

What is the way to mark the checkbox when clicking on the BOB text?
In my example I need to check the box also by clicking on the text BOB .
I would be happy to help with this.
I add the reducer and the action of the checxbox .
hope u can understand the way of it .

this is the **reducer**

```
import {
  SET_CURRENT_TAB_INFO,
  SET_CURRENT_TAB_NAME,
  SET_CURRENT_TIME,
  SET_CHECKBOX,
  SET_CHECKBOX2,
  SET_REQUESTID,
  SET_IS_FORM_CHECKED,
  SET_INPUTS_TEXT,
} from '../../constants/BitzuaDigumConstants';

const initializeState = {
  currentTabName: '',
  currentTabInfo: null,
  currentTime: '',
  checkBox: false,
  checkBox2: false,
  requestId: 0,
  isFormChecked: false,
  inputsText: {}
};

export default function BitzuaDigumReducer(state = initializeState, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case SET_CURRENT_TAB_NAME:
      return {
        ...state,
        currentTabName: action.payload,
      };
    case SET_IS_FORM_CHECKED:
      return {
        ...state,
        isFormChecked: action.payload,
      };
    case SET_INPUTS_TEXT:
      return {
        ...state,
        inputsText: action.payload,
      };
    case SET_CURRENT_TAB_INFO:
      if (!action.payload) {
        return state;
      }

      if (!state.currentTabInfo) {
        // here if currentTabInfo == null
        return {
          ...state,
          currentTabInfo: action.payload, // it will set the value from payload
        };
      }
      // if currentTabInfo already had some values (it means it not null)

      return {
        ...state,
        currentTabInfo: {
          ...state.currentTabInfo,
          ...action.payload,
        },
      };
    case SET_CURRENT_TIME:
      return {
        ...state,
        currentTime: action.payload,
      };
    case SET_CHECKBOX:
      return {
        ...state,
        checkBox: action.payload,
      };
    case SET_CHECKBOX2:
      return {
        ...state,
        checkBox2: action.payload,
      };
    case SET_REQUESTID:
      return {
        ...state,
        requestId: action.payload,
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

this is the **dispatch action**

```
export function setCheckBox(data = false) {
  const payload = data;
  return { type: SET_CHECKBOX, payload };
}
```

```
import { setCheckBox } from '../redux/actions/BitzuaDigumActions';

function NetuneyDigum(props) {
const isSelected = useSelector(
    (rootState) => rootState.BitzuaDigumReducer.checkBox
  );

return (
<TouchableOpacity
            activeOpacity={1}
            style={{
              flexDirection: 'row',
              alignSelf: 'flex-start',
              top: 20,
              left: 10,
            }}
          >
            <CheckBox
              value={isSelected}
              onValueChange={(value) => dispatch(setCheckBox(value))}
              style={styles.checkbox}
              tintColors={{ true: 'white', false: 'white' }}
            />
            <Text style={styles.label}>BOB</Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>
 );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways here:
You can set the `onPress` property either on the `TouchableOpacity` component or on the `Text`. In React Native all Text components are touchable. And set the `onPress` to change the value of the checkbox similarly to what you have on `onValueChange`. I don't know exactly what the code would look like because I don't know what you are doing in your dispatch action.

Edit:

Example:

add this to `Text`:
`onPress={(value) => dispatch(toggleCheckBox())}`

Create this function:

```
export function toggleCheckBox() {
  return { type: TOGGLE_CHECKBOX };
}
```

Add this to the reducer:

```
case TOGGLE_CHECKBOX:
  return {
    ...state,
    checkBox: !state.checkBox,
  };
```

Comment: i edit my question above - u can see the dispatch action

Comment: You should probably have an action to toggle the value of the checkbox that simply sets it to false when it's true and to true when it's false

Comment: sure. Show me the reducer please

Comment: I just edited the answer to showcase the toggle functionality

Comment: @Kira24 If this helped you and you think the answer is correct, please select it as the correct answer. Thank you!

Comment: i need pass the value={isSelected} into the text .. how i do it ?